# Pandas to parse the text data and assign the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have below text data what I want to be parsed with `pandas` into column data. I need to have four columns as per four rows.

In the `My trial` output we need `VC_VERSION`  to be splited into `VC_ACTIVE_VERSION` & `VC_STANDBY_VERSION`

### raw data:

```
========= enc1001 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1002 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1003 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1004 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1005 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1006 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1007 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1008 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.40
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.40
========= enc1009 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2001 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2002 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2003 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2004 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2005 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2006 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2007 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2008 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2009 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2011 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2013 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3020 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc3021 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc3022 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc3026 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.45
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.45
========= enc3027 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3028 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3029 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3030 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3031 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4021 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4023 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4024 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4025 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4026 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4027 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4028 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4029 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4030 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4031 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4032 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4033 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4034 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc6002 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6011 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6012 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6013 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6014 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6015 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6016 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6017 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc7002 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
========= enc7003 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
========= enc7004 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
========= enc7009 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1010 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1011 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1012 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1013 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1014 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1015 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1016 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1017 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1018 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1025 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc1026 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2010 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2012 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2014 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2015 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2016 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2018 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2019 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2020 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2021 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2022 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2023 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3033 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3034 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3036 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4020 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4022 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4035 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc7005 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc7006 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC FlexFabric 10Gb/24-Port Module  4.50
  2 HP VC FlexFabric 10Gb/24-Port Module  4.50
========= enc7007 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc7008 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8001 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8017 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8018 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8019 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8021 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8022 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8023 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8024 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8025 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8026 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8027 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8028 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8033 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.40
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.40
```

### My trial:

```
df  = pd.read_csv("file.txt", names=["col1"])
df = df.col1.str.split(' ', expand = True)
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11]], axis=1)

df = df.rename(columns={ 1: 'ENC_NAME', 9: 'VC_VERSION', 10: 'OA_VERSION'})

print(df)

       ENC_NAME VC_VERSION OA_VERSION
0    enc1001       None       None
1                   KVM       4.85
2                  4.50       None
3                  4.50       None
4    enc1002       None       None
5                   KVM       4.85
6                  4.50       None
7                  4.50       None
8    enc1003       None       None
9                   KVM       4.85
10                 4.50       None
11                 4.50       None
12   enc1004       None       None
13                  KVM       4.85
14                 4.50       None
15                 4.50       None
----------------- data snipped ---------------
```

### Desired:

```
   ENC_NAME OA_VERSION VC_ACTIVE VC_STDN
    enc1001       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc1002       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc1003       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc1004       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc1005       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc1006       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc1007       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc1008       4.85      4.40    4.40
    enc1009       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc2001       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc2002       4.85      4.50    4.50
    enc2003       4.85      4.50    4.50
```

Please help to get with pandas.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following takes the `ENC_NAME` from the header rows (with `=` signs) and the last value from all other rows assuming that rows are in the desired order. We then assign row and col numbers and pivot.

The advantage is that it doesn't depend on the number of spaces in your data.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\n',header=None, names=['col1'])

df['row'] = df.col1.str.contains('===').cumsum()
df['col'] = df.groupby('row').cumcount()
df['value'] = df.col1.str.extract('=== (.*) ===')
m = df.value.isna()
df.loc[m,'value'] = df.loc[m,'col1'].str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)$').values

df = df.pivot('row','col','value')
df.columns = ['ENC_NAME', 'OA_VERSION', 'VC_ACTIVE', 'VC_STDN']
```

Result:

```
    ENC_NAME OA_VERSION VC_ACTIVE VC_STDN
row                                      
1    enc1001       4.85      4.50    4.50
2    enc1002       4.85      4.50    4.50
3    enc1003       4.85      4.50    4.50
4    enc1004       4.85      4.50    4.50
5    enc1005       4.85      4.50    4.50
6    enc1006       4.85      4.50    4.50
7    enc1007       4.85      4.50    4.50
8    enc1008       4.85      4.40    4.40
9    enc1009       4.85      4.50    4.50
10   enc2001       4.85      4.50    4.50
11   enc2002       4.85      4.50    4.50
12   enc2003       4.85      4.50    4.50
13   enc2004       4.85      4.50    4.50
14   enc2005       4.85      4.50    4.50
15   enc2006       4.85      4.50    4.50
16   enc2007       4.85      4.50    4.50
17   enc2008       4.85      4.50    4.50
18   enc2009       4.85      4.50    4.50
19   enc2011       4.85      4.50    4.50
20   enc2013       4.85      4.50    4.50
21   enc3020       4.85      4.41    4.41
22   enc3021       4.85      4.41    4.41
23   enc3022       4.85      4.41    4.41
24   enc3026       4.85      4.45    4.45
25   enc3027       4.85      4.50    4.50
26   enc3028       4.85      4.50    4.50
27   enc3029       4.85      4.50    4.50
28   enc3030       4.85      4.50    4.50
29   enc3031       4.85      4.50    4.50
30   enc4021       4.85      4.41    4.41
31   enc4023       4.85      4.41    4.41
32   enc4024       4.85      4.41    4.41
33   enc4025       4.85      4.41    4.41
34   enc4026       4.85      4.50    4.50
35   enc4027       4.85      4.50    4.50
36   enc4028       4.85      4.50    4.50
37   enc4029       4.85      4.50    4.50
38   enc4030       4.85      4.50    4.50
39   enc4031       4.85      4.50    4.50
40   enc4032       4.85      4.50    4.50
41   enc4033       4.85      4.50    4.50
42   enc4034       4.85      4.50    4.50
43   enc6002       4.60       NaN     NaN
44   enc6011       4.60       NaN     NaN
45   enc6012       4.60       NaN     NaN
46   enc6013       4.60       NaN     NaN
47   enc6014       4.60       NaN     NaN
48   enc6015       4.60       NaN     NaN
49   enc6016       4.60       NaN     NaN
50   enc6017       4.60       NaN     NaN
51   enc7002       4.85       NaN     NaN
52   enc7003       4.85       NaN     NaN
53   enc7004       4.85       NaN     NaN
54   enc7009       4.85      4.50    4.50
55   enc1010       4.85      4.50    4.50
56   enc1011       4.85      4.50    4.50
57   enc1012       4.85      4.50    4.50
58   enc1013       4.85      4.50    4.50
59   enc1014       4.85      4.50    4.50
60   enc1015       4.85      4.50    4.50
61   enc1016       4.85      4.50    4.50
62   enc1017       4.85      4.50    4.50
63   enc1018       4.85      4.50    4.50
64   enc1025       4.85      4.62    4.62
65   enc1026       4.85      4.50    4.50
66   enc2010       4.85      4.50    4.50
67   enc2012       4.85      4.50    4.50
68   enc2014       4.85      4.50    4.50
69   enc2015       4.85      4.50    4.50
70   enc2016       4.85      4.50    4.50
71   enc2018       4.85      4.50    4.50
72   enc2019       4.85      4.50    4.50
73   enc2020       4.85      4.50    4.50
74   enc2021       4.85      4.50    4.50
75   enc2022       4.85      4.50    4.50
76   enc2023       4.85      4.50    4.50
77   enc3033       4.85      4.50    4.50
78   enc3034       4.85      4.50    4.50
79   enc3036       4.85      4.50    4.50
80   enc4020       4.85      4.41    4.41
81   enc4022       4.85      4.41    4.41
82   enc4035       4.85      4.50    4.50
83   enc7005       4.85      4.50    4.50
84   enc7006       4.85      4.50    4.50
85   enc7007       4.85      4.62    4.62
86   enc7008       4.85      4.62    4.62
87   enc8001       4.85      4.50    4.50
88   enc8017       4.85      4.50    4.50
89   enc8018       4.85      4.50    4.50
90   enc8019       4.85      4.50    4.50
91   enc8021       4.85      4.50    4.50
92   enc8022       4.85      4.62    4.62
93   enc8023       4.85      4.62    4.62
94   enc8024       4.85      4.62    4.62
95   enc8025       4.85      4.62    4.62
96   enc8026       4.85      4.62    4.62
97   enc8027       4.85      4.62    4.62
98   enc8028       4.85      4.62    4.62
99   enc8033       4.85      4.40    4.40
```

Comment: @ Stef, thanks for the solution, this works as expected, Can you please explain

`m = df.value.isna()`

and 


`df.loc[m,'value'] = df.loc[m,'col1'].str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)$').values`

Comment: `m` is a mask for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). After we filled the `value` column the ENC_NAMEs, all other rows of this column have NaN (i.e. missing) values. `isna()` selects these rows (sets the mask to True). Then we only fill these rows of the `value` column with the extracted numbers and leave the already filled rows unchanged by assigning only to `df.loc[m,'value']` instead of `df['value']`.

Answer (score 1):

I would try downfilling the ENC_NAME and then doing a pivot. I wasn't sure exactly how to identify the values that you were looking for.

I assumed that :

`1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module` corresponds with `VC_ACTIVE`

and

`2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module` corresponds with `VC_STDN`

If there's a better way to identify the values, you could change the filter conditions in my code below.

#### Code

```
df  = pd.read_csv("file.txt", names=["col1"])
df = df.col1.str.split(' ', expand = True)
df[1] = df[1].replace("",None).ffill()

df["colname"] = np.where(
    df[9] == "KVM", "OA_VERSION", np.where(
    df[2] == "1", "VC_ACTIVE", np.where(
    df[2] == "2", "VC_STDN", None)))
    
df["value"] = np.where(
    df[9] == "KVM", df[10], np.where(
    df[2] == "1", df[9], np.where(
    df[2] == "2", df[9], None)))

df["ENC_NAME"] = df[1]

df = df.pivot(index="ENC_NAME", columns="colname", values="value")\
[["OA_VERSION", "VC_ACTIVE", "VC_STDN"]]\
.reset_index()

df.columns.name = None

print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
ENC_NAME OA_VERSION VC_ACTIVE VC_STDN
enc1001       4.85      4.50    4.50
enc1002       4.85      4.50    4.50
enc1003       4.85      4.50    4.50
enc1004       4.85      4.50    4.50
enc1005       4.85      4.50    4.50
enc1006       4.85      4.50    4.50
enc1007       4.85      4.50    4.50
enc1008       4.85      4.40    4.40
enc1009       4.85      4.50    4.50
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 already, but i see the `KeyError: 10`  & `KeyError: 9`. can you explain `np.where`  condition in code so i can change the value.

Comment: The np.where condition is filtering by column value. There may be an inconsistency in the way the spaces are read, causing inconsistencies in the shape of the df and leading to the keyerror. You could experiment with the column indexes until you find the correct columns. It may be 8 and 9 instead of 9 and 10 for example. But I think Stef's answer is a bit more stable because it doesn't rely on the spaces at all.